# Need help moving item between lists with Java using swing

Tags: java, swing

I need my to move items from the left side, list, to the right side, list_1, using my add button. The remove button needs to remove the items from the right list. I've had trouble finishing this part out.

```
package com.cooksys.assessment;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;
import java.awt.Font;

public class Window {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application. The main method is the entry point to a Java application. 
 * For this assessment, you shouldn't have to add anything to this.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Window window = new Window();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application. This is the constructor for this Window class.
 * All of the code here will be executed as soon as a Window object is made.
 */
public Window() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame. This is where Window Builder
 * will generate its code.
 */
public void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 479);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    JMenuItem mntmLoad = new JMenuItem("Load");
    mnFile.add(mntmLoad);

    JMenuItem mntmSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
    mnFile.add(mntmSave);

    JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    mnFile.add(mntmExit);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton remove = new JButton("<<");
    remove.setBounds(173, 222, 79, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(remove);

    JButton Add = new JButton(">>");
    Add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
    });
    Add.setBounds(173, 188, 79, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Add);

    JList list = new JList();
    list.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    list.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {
        String[] values = new String[] {"Case", "Motherboard", "CPU", "RAM",       "GPU", "HDD", "PSU"};
        public int getSize() {
            return values.length;
        }
        public Object getElementAt(int index) {
            return values[index];
        }
    });
    list.setBounds(0, 0, 161, 419);
    frame.getContentPane().add(list);

    JList list_1 = new JList();
    list_1.setBounds(262, 0, 172, 419);
    frame.getContentPane().add(list_1);



    }
}
```

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for a working example that shows how to add/remove items for a JList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you should set list selection mode with this code:

```
list.setSelectionMode( mode );
```

which mode can be one of following modes:

1. `ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION`
2. `ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION`
3. `ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION`

Also use `DefaultListModel` instead of `AbstractListModel`.

By setting third mode to lists you can select multiple items from each list by holding ctrl button and clicking them.

And in buttons `ActionListener`s use `list.getSelectedValuesList()` to get list of selected values, now all you need is to use a loop and add values from `source list` to `destination list`, **also remove it from source list**.

## I changed few parts of your code:

- **Deleted**

  - `AbstractListModel` for `list`
- **Added**

  - `DefaultListModel` to lists

    - `model_list` for `list`
    - `model_list_1` for `list_1`
  - `ActionListener` to remove button.

All of my changes are commented in code, read them to know about each part.

## Here is The CODE WITHOUT RENAMING VARIABLES:

 
**in order to work properly i had to move some codes inside your code.**

```
package com.cooksys.assessment;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

public class Window {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application. The main method is the entry point to a Java
     * application. For this assessment, you shouldn't have to add anything to
     * this.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Window window = new Window();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application. This is the constructor for this Window class.
     * All of the code here will be executed as soon as a Window object is made.
     */
    public Window() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame. This is where Window Builder will
     * generate its code.
     */
    public void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 479);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        String[] values = new String[]{"Case", "Motherboard", "CPU", "RAM", "GPU", "HDD", "PSU"};

        // using default list model.
        DefaultListModel model_list = new DefaultListModel();
        DefaultListModel model_list_1 = new DefaultListModel();

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);

        JMenuItem mntmLoad = new JMenuItem("Load");
        mnFile.add(mntmLoad);

        JMenuItem mntmSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
        mnFile.add(mntmSave);

        JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        mnFile.add(mntmExit);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JList list = new JList();
        JList list_1 = new JList();

        JButton remove = new JButton("<<");
        remove.setBounds(173, 222, 79, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(remove);

        JButton Add = new JButton(">>");
        Add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // get list of selected values and for each one of them do following
                list.getSelectedValuesList().stream().forEach((data) -> {
                    // moving data
                    model_list_1.addElement(data);
                    // remove from other side
                    model_list.removeElement(data);
                });
                // refreshing the view after changes
                list.revalidate();
                list_1.revalidate();
            }
        });

        Add.setBounds(173, 188, 79, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(Add);

        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        list.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        list.setBounds(0, 0, 161, 419);
        list.setModel(model_list);
        frame.getContentPane().add(list);
                    list_1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        list_1.setBounds(262, 0, 172, 419);
        list_1.setModel(model_list_1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(list_1);                

        // Add values to list using list_model
        for (String value : values) {
            model_list.addElement(value);
        }

        remove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                list_1.getSelectedValuesList().stream().forEach((data) -> {
                    model_list.addElement(data);
                    model_list_1.removeElement(data);
                });
                list.revalidate();
                list_1.revalidate();
            }
        });       

    } 
}
```